# Very first Query in AWS Athena Takes long time to get response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

When i have started with putting the data(compressed, split and partitioned) in s3 and querying through AWS Athena, I felt that first query takes long time to get results, but later query response is quick. But when I try query after a period of time the same happens.
why this happens? Is there any configuration change that should be done to improve this issue?

Comment: Are the subsequent queries same as the first query?

I faced the same issue. When using a client, the taken for the client to retrieve data from Athena was 2-3 seconds more than the time shown in the console. I contact AWS support resgarding this and they replied that they use caching mechanism.

Comment: Yeah the same query or any other queries are fine. The first query takes 70 secs or above sometimes, but subsequent queries takes below 6 seconds